# Fetching long value from Database

Tags: java, jdbc

My database contains a field `ARR_ID` with data type as `NUMBER(20)`,

the value is = `100013085001`

Some java application is fetching this value and they are using `Integer` as the datatype to fetch the value.

In the output of their application the value is displayed as `1228837193`.

How is this value getting converted in Java I do not know?
What happens when the data is too large to be contained in the datatype?
Shouldn't the application throw an error in that case?

Comment: Use BigInteger [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for Big Integer Number and BigDecimal [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for Big Decimal Number.

Comment: What is the database, which driver + version and what code is used to retrieve the value?

Comment: @ravi The value shown can fit in a long, so there is no need to use BigInteger.

Comment: the database is Oracle 11g. I am not sure about the other details. Code is from a different Application that I do not own. They use JDBC connection to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the SQL driver you are using. I saw the circumstances you are describing once when I was using the SQLite driver. I was also a bit concerned and checked the sources. The datatype is determinded by the value in the column. If it doesn't fit in an `Integer` a `Long` is used.

I don't remember how this is working for a collection. You may want to check the sources of the driver which you are using (if it's also open source).

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDBC then with a 20-digit integer (e.g. 12345678901234567890), the program throws com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException: '1.2345678901234567E19' in column '1' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER.  It seems you use Oracle which I don't have, this is for mysql, you may try for yourself.